# Factoring a probability distribution containing a latent variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, hierarchical-bayesian, latent-variable

I distribution which involves 3 parameters, which I'll call (for now) $P(z | y, x)$.  However, one of the parameters is a function of another.

For instance, let the random variable $y$ be a function of the random variable $x$, $y = f(x)$.  Associated with this functional relationship between $y$ and $x$ I have on hand $P(y | x)$.  My main point of confusion is that there is another random variable involved, $z$.  The difference between $y = f(x)$ and $z$ is a Gaussian distribution:
$$
P(z | y, x) = C exp(-\frac{(z - f(x))^2}{2\sigma^2}) = Cexp(-\frac{(z - y)^2}{2\sigma^2})
$$
But to me it also makes sense that I could say that,
$$
P(z | y) = C exp(-\frac{(z - f(x))^2}{2\sigma^2}) = Cexp(-\frac{(z - y)^2}{2\sigma^2})
$$
because the actual value of $x$ doesn't appear in the probability distribution function.

**What is the correct way to write down the conditionality of this pdf?**
Is this $P(z | y, x)$, or $P(z | y)$?  Or perhaps this should be denoted $P(z | y)P(y | x)$?

I don't think it's just $P(z | y)$ because the value of $y$ is of course strongly dependent on a particular value of $x$.  On the other hand, $P(z | x)$ isn't really defined, because $z$ and $x$ are only related through latent variable $y$.

The reason I'm wondering is because this situation comes up as a step in a Bayesian model I am working on and I need to be able to accurately use the probability chain rule and Bayes' theorem to devise a sampling strategy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After thinking this through more, I found the fault in my reasoning.  The answer is that the distribution is denoted $P(z | y, x)$.

This is true because of independence.  $x$ and $y$ are obviously not independent.  The only way you could have $P(z | y)$ is by integrating $\int P(z | y, x) dx$